# Count unique page visits without counting refresh as page visit

Tags: php, counter, visitor-pattern

I am making visitor counter for my website but it counts when the page is refreshed. I want to count only unique user visit.

```
             $logfile = "visitors.txt";

           if (file_exists($logfile)) {

           $handle = fopen($logfile, "r");
            $log = fread($handle, filesize($logfile));
           fclose($handle);
            } else {
              die ("The log file doesn't exist!");
            }

         `Seperate each logline`
         $log = explode("\n", trim($log));


          // Seperate each part in each logline//
          for ($i = 0; $i < count($log); $i++) {
          $log[$i] = trim($log[$i]);
          $log[$i] = explode('|', $log[$i]);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is code to detect whether page was refreshed or not:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0') {
    //Code to execute when page refresh.
} else {
    //Code to execute when page not refresh.
}
```

If returns `true` then page refreshed otherwise not.

**EDIT: TRY THIS**

```
$pageRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
if (!$pageRefreshed) {
    $count = (string) $getvisitorcount[0]["count"];
    $noZeros = 7;
    $displayZeros = 7 - strlen($count);
    $visitor = "";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $displayZeros; $i++) {
        $visitor .= (string) 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's returning the value as 'True'

Comment: It means page refreshed. So write your code in condition such that it executes only if page not refreshed.

Comment: This is the piece of code,$count = (string)$getvisitorcount[0]["count"];
                        $noZeros = 7;
                        $displayZeros = 7-strlen($count);
                        $visitor = "";
                        for($i=1;$i<=$displayZeros;$i++){
                            $visitor .=(string)0;
                        }   can you please explain how can i remove the refresh conditon

Comment: When this code should be executed? On page refresh or not.

Comment: I have added this code in the footer, so I want to count only one count on basis of unique IP address but now when I refresh the page the count is increasing by 1